# Filter info, from link, in python?

Tags: python, html

So i"m writing a program in Python to pull the rating for a movie, from one of my favorite sites.

Example link to review:
http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/entertainment/movie-reviews/hindi/Madras-Cafe-movie-review/movie-review/21975443.cms

Presently, I'm using string.partition commands, to get parts of the source html code, which contain the rating info. However, this method is extremely slow.

What would be the fastest way to get the movie's rating?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#POST Request to TOI site, for review source
data_output = requests.post(review_link)

#Clean HTML code
soup = BeautifulSoup(data_output.text)

#Filter source data, via a dirty string partition method

#rating
texted = str(soup).partition(" stars,")
texted = texted[0].partition("Rating: ")
rating = texted[2]
#title
texted = texted[0].partition(" movie review")
texted = texted[0].partition("<title>")
title = texted[2]

#print stuff
print "Title:", title
print "Rating:", rating, "/ 5"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Using an actual HTML parser would be helpful; like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Posting an example of your code would be beneficial too

Comment: i tried BeautifulSoup, however, it takes longer, since there is no real html tag that holds the rating. Instead I had to use the search_all method, which is just as time-consuming.

Comment: I'm posting code now, however I thought I wouldn't need to since I was trying a basic string.partition command.

Comment: I did something similar to IMDB with `HTMLParser` and it is fine.

Comment: @SAM - could you share the code you used? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to get the html, [lxml](http://lxml.de/) for parsing html and getting the rating value, and [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for extracting  actual rating as a number:

```
import re
from lxml import etree
import requests

URL = "http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/entertainment/movie-reviews/hindi/Madras-Cafe-movie-review/movie-review/21975443.cms"

response = requests.get(URL)

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
root = etree.fromstring(response.text, parser=parser)
rating_text = root.find('.//div[@id="sshow"]/table/tr/td[2]/div[1]/script[1]').text  # prints fbcriticRating="4"; 
print re.search("\d+", rating_text).group(0)  # prints 4
```

Note, that you are not required to use `requests` here - you may use `urllib2` instead, this is just an example. The main part is parsing html and getting the rating value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great solution… but when you're doing stuff that would be just as simple with the stdlib `urllib2` and `xml.etree.ElementTree`, why pull in extra requirements? (There are certainly cases where `requests` and/or `lxml.etree` are better, but this doesn't seem to be one of them.)

Comment: @abarnert good point, thank you. This is just an example and we are all humans - so, we should use libraries "for humans" :)

Comment: @abarnert well, the rating value is pretty well "hidden" in an html, getting it by xpath looks pretty logical and convenient..

Comment: For the first comment, is `urllib2.urlopen(URL)` really not human-readable? As I said, there are certainly cases where `urllib2` _is_ painful, and `requests` solves things… but you're solving a problem that doesn't exist here.

Comment: And for the second… the stdlib ElementTree has XPath support, just as the lxml clone of the stdlib API does. So again, why require an external library (and in this case one that requires a C extension, and which on many platforms also requires installing a separate C library just so you can build that extension, and on some platforms has additional problems trying to get around an older version of the same library that may already exist, and …)?

Comment: @abarnert thank you for reasonable criticism! Tried to parse the page using `ElementTree` from stdlib - got `not well-formed` error..

Comment: Well, that would certainly be a good reason to not use the stdlib… And I don't think anyone would expect you to spend time debugging that when you've already got a working solution. I just thought it was worth pointing out that you (meaning the OP, or a future reader) can start with the stdlib, instead of implying that there's no way to even get started without building a bunch of C libraries.

Comment: @abarnert sure, just wanted to provide an example with `ElementTree` too. Installing `lxml` usually costs me about 3 cups of coffee :) Sorry, I'm just learning how to answer in a clean and good way. Doing things wrong sometimes - will learn :)

Comment: Unless the OP comes back saying "I don't have a compiler and can't install one" or "I'm stumped trying to get lxml to build" or something, this is already fine. If you want to put in more work to add more alternative examples, that might make it even _better_, but it's already good.

Comment: I don't mind using Requests, since I'm using it already elsewhere in my code. I don't actually have a compiler right now, however, I'll be using this code elsewhere, where I'll be able to compile code. I thought lxml might work, but since I don't have a compiler, I wasn't able to test it out. This seems like a good solution. I'll test it out. Thanks!